# Toolbar without icon, but with title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I want to have a `Toolbar` without icon (**AND WITHOUD EMPTY SPACE BETWEEN LEFT BORDER AND TITLE**), but with title like on screen below:

[image]

Tried different combinations of `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` methods, but can't achieve this. What i get is:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve what is on 1st screen without defining custom `Toolbar` (i want to treat `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` to have `menu items`)?

My `themes.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Comment: Could you post your code and xmls - layout with toolbar and relevant menu?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak it doesn't matter, let it be abc_toolbar

Comment: Post your code of your activity and style which you use in your activity as theme. You have to have something wrong in your code. Because it is not standard behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
final Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.YOUR_TITLE);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

and in your App theme in `style.xml`, add:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: i still get empty space between left border and a title

Comment: I try my code, the result is same as your 1st screenshot.

Comment: found mistake in Toolbar xml file (had app:contentInsetStart="72dp")